# ReactJs - Sort method

Tags: javascript, sorting, html-table, character-encoding

I have a table in my react app and it gets its data from API.

I want to sort one of its columns. `a[obj1][obj2]` or `b[obj1][obj2]` Usually is a string of numbers and sometimes are equal to `"-"` `(Dash)`
this is my sort function:

```
if (order === "DEF") {
  const sorted = props.currency.sort((a, b) =>
    Number(a[obj1][obj2]) > Number(b[obj1][obj2])
      ? 1
      : Number(b[obj1][obj2]) > Number(a[obj1][obj2]) || a[obj1][obj2] === "-"
      ? -1
      : 0
  );
  props.setCurrency(sorted);
  setOrder("ASC");
} else if (order === "ASC") {
  const sorted = props.currency.sort((a, b) =>
    Number(a[obj1][obj2]) < Number(b[obj1][obj2]) || a[obj1][obj2] === "-"
      ? 1
      : Number(b[obj1][obj2]) < Number(a[obj1][obj2])
      ? -1
      : 0
  );
  props.setCurrency(sorted);
  setOrder("DSC");
} else {
  const sorted = defaultCurrency;
  props.setCurrency(sorted);
  setOrder("DEF");
}
```

After the sort is called I want to behave with `"-"` like a zero,
but the items which are equal to `"-"`are always placed on the top of the table when the order is equal to **ASC** or **DSC**, while the other items of the array are sorted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to behave with "-" like a zero then in the sort function you can add this as your first condition and return 0.

```
.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[obj1][obj2] === "-") return 0;
    return Number(a[obj1][obj2]) > Number(b[obj1][obj2]) ? 1
     : Number(b[obj1][obj2]) > Number(a[obj1][obj2]) ? -1 : 0
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this significantly by parsing the compared elements first, and then applying simple logic for the sorting.

Here declaring a single `customSort` which accepts an array, a function for retreiving the relevant property from each element, and a direction boolean which defaults to `ascending: true`.

The value of each element is then accessed using the passed function and converted to a number (here with [unary `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus)).

Finally the elements are sorted first by whether either `isNaN` otherwise by subrtracting based on the direction boolean.

```js
const customSort = (arr, prop, asc = true) => {
  return [...arr].sort((a, b) => {
    a = +prop(a);
    b = +prop(b);

    return isNaN(a) - isNaN(b) || (asc ? a - b : b - a);
  })
}

const data = [{ prop1: { prop2: '2' } }, { prop1: { prop2: '5' } }, { prop1: { prop2: '3' } }, { prop1: { prop2: '1' } }, { prop1: { prop2: '-' } }, { prop1: { prop2: '9' } }, { prop1: { prop2: '-' } },];
const obj1 = 'prop1';
const obj2 = 'prop2';

console.log(customSort(data, (o) => o[obj1][obj2], true));
console.log(customSort(data, (o) => o[obj1][obj2], false));
```